# Merging multiple Audio files using the Command Prompt in Windows 11

Tags: command-prompt

I am trying to combine multiple audio files in a folder into one larger file using the command line but I keep getting this error.

```
PS C:\Users\thegr\Desktop\code\projects\champloo\ep_05> copy /b *.mp3 Samurai_champloo_05.mp3
Copy-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument
'Samurai_champloo_05.mp3'.
At line:1 char:1
+ copy /b *.mp3 Samurai_champloo_05.mp3
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Copy-Item], ParameterBindingExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Comm
   ands.CopyItemCommand
```

I'm not sure why it isn't working. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Run cmd.exe as Administrator to run the "copy" command.

Reference: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-itpro-docs/issues/6846